# Adding day of the week column according to multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

How to add the `day_of_week` column(the day of the week, eg. 1 = Mon, 2 = Tue) to `df1` according to the `year`,`month`,`day` values as shown below:

```
    year month day  A       B       C   D       day_of_week
0   2019    1   1   26.2    20.2    0.0 32.4        2
1   2019    1   2   22.9    20.3    0.0 10.0        3
2   2019    1   3   24.8    18.4    0.0 28.8        4
3   2019    1   4   26.6    18.3    0.0 33.5        5
4   2019    1   5   28.3    20.9    0.0 33.4        6
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime.today().weekday()` should do the job. But Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. So, you need to add one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime` and `.dt.dayofweek` attribute and plus `1`

```
df['day_of_week'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']], 
                                   errors='coerce').dt.dayofweek + 1

Out[410]:
   year  month  day     A     B    C     D  day_of_week
0  2019      1    1  26.2  20.2  0.0  32.4            2
1  2019      1    2  22.9  20.3  0.0  10.0            3
2  2019      1    3  24.8  18.4  0.0  28.8            4
3  2019      1    4  26.6  18.3  0.0  33.5            5
4  2019      1    5  28.3  20.9  0.0  33.4            6
```

Comment: How come it returned `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`? What does it mean?

Comment: @nilsinelabore: some values in your `year`, `month`, `day` are invalid. I added `coerce` to ignore them. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want the day name, you can make use of `calendar`.

```
import datetime
import calendar

def findDay(date):
    day_number = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d %m %Y').weekday() + 1
    day_name = calendar.day_name[day_number-1]
    return (day_number, day_name)
```

You can generate a date in `str` format using something like this `date = f'{day} {month} {year}'` from the `year, month, day` columns.

Then all you have to do is apply the function above on the new date column. The function will return a tuple with the day number of the week as well as the day name.